# Google Cloud Functions Gen 2 - Idle Period Before Scaling to Zero

Tags: google-cloud-functions

I have a Gen 2 Google Cloud Function that's triggered by a message on a pub / sub topic. The rate of messages is fixed at one message every 30 minutes.

The Cloud Functions instance graph shows that the function is moved to an idle state after serving a request and stays idle for 15 minutes before the instance is shut down.

Is there a way to reduce the idle period (ideally set it to as close to zero as possible) as I know that the function will not be called again for another 30 minutes after serving the request?

A low cold start time is not a requirement for this function.

Comment: Why do you want to shutdown your instance? You don't pay it when you are out of request processing.

Comment: It's just an environmental resource use consideration. I assume that even when idle the function / Cloud Run instance is consuming some memory / CPU resource - which will be consuming a tiny amount of electricity, which will be generating a tiny amount of heat, which will need dissipating with some form of active cooling. I feel that it's useful to consider efficient code execution paths and resource use because when multiplied trillions of times in all the devices / computers in the world it can have a big effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments [you are not charged for idle instances](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/about-instance-autoscaling#idle-instance) unless:

1. You have [configured the CPU to be always allocated](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/configuring/cpu-allocation#pricing-impact)
2. You have configured [min-instances](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/configuring/min-instances#billing)

Although those links refer to Cloud Run they are applicable to Gen 2 functions because those run on Cloud Run. You also can read more about the specific [billing practices for Cloud Functions](https://cloud.google.com/functions/pricing#compute_time).

Either way, there is no direct method available to shut down an idle instance. The [container runtime contract](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/container-contract#lifecycle-services) explains this in more detail. But it also illustrates a method to force shutdown of an instance:

> A Cloud Run container instance that exceeds the allowed memory limit is terminated. All requests that are still processing on the container instance end with an HTTP 500 error.

Therefore, a very ugly hack to force the instance to shutdown would be to configure your function to accept a specially crafted PubSub message that instructs it to fill its memory beyond its defined capacity. For example, in a Node function you can use `crypto.randomBytes()`:

```
import * as crypto from 'crypto'
import { type Message } from '@google-cloud/pubsub'

const fillMemory = (length: number): Buffer => {
  return crypto.randomBytes(length)
}

export const yourCloudFunction = async (message: Message): Promise<void> => {
  const data: string = Buffer.from(message.data.toString(), 'base64').toString()

  if (data === 'kill instance') {
    fillMemory(1073741824) // 1 GB
  }
}
```

Comment: Hey, you can do much simpler! os.exit(0) is enough to exit and stop the instance!